# How to create keystore and truststore file for opendistro elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, openssl, elasticsearch-opendistro

I am using Open Distro for Elasticsearch rpm. I have setup my LDAP server in config.yml. However when I start my elasticsearch cluster, it gives me this error "Empty file path for opendistro_security.ssl.transport.truststore_
filepath". I am using demo certificates which are given by open distro. Can someone please tell me how can I generate keystore and truststore for demo certificates in Opendistro for elasticsearch?

I tried using demo certificates, but it is not working.

The error I am getting is 
`Empty file path for opendistro_security.ssl.transport.truststore_filepath`

Comment: Everything should be explained here: https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/security-configuration/generate-certificates/ Try it out and let us know if that still doesn't work

Comment: @Val Thank you for your response. I followed the steps to generate all these certificates. I am also following the demo blog from [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/add-ssl-certificates-open-distro-for-elasticsearch/ )

Where it says in kibana.yml file add lines

` 
server.ssl.enabled: true
server.ssl.key: <full path to your key file>
server.ssl.certificate: <full path to your certificate>
 `

Thank you!
I don't understand which certificate path to put?  Do I need to put **esnode-key.pem** and **esnode.pem** ? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: As [explained here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/configuring-tls.html), you need to generate another certificate for Kibana, which is used to encrypt the communication between the browser and the Kibana server.

Comment: @Val thank you. I will try out that solution.

Comment: @Val I generated all the certificates required and tried to run the securityadmin.sh script, with all the cert paths I am getting this error when I run that script:

`Cannot retrieve cluster state due to: No user found for cluster:monitor/health. This is not an error, will keep on trying ...
  Root cause: ElasticsearchSecurityException[No user found for cluster:monitor/health] (org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSecurityException/org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSecurityException)`

Comment: @Val here is the content of my elasticsearch file
`opendistro_security.ssl.transport.pemcert_filepath: /etc/elasticsearch/config/node.pem
opendistro_security.ssl.transport.pemkey_filepath: /etc/elasticsearch/config/node-key.pem
opendistro_security.ssl.transport.pemtrustedcas_filepath: /etc/elasticsearch/config/root-ca.pem
opendistro_security.ssl.http.enabled: true
opendistro_security.ssl.http.pemcert_filepath: /etc/elasticsearch/config/node.pem
opendistro_security.ssl.http.pemkey_filepath: /etc/elasticsearch/config/node-key.pem
`

Comment: @Val I got SSL working but I still dont know what to put for ` opendistro_security.ssl.transport.truststore_filepath` should it be admin, root or node?